# JS: can a hash map be used to keep track while iterating this array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to practice some algorithm questions and I'm stumped on the best way to solve this.  I can obviously have nested for loops but that doesn't seem efficient.  Can I use a hash map to track the temp and index of the temp?

**Given a list of daily temperatures, produce a list that, for each day in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait until a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, put 0 instead.
For example, given the list temperatures = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73], your output should be [1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0].**

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: What happens if you start looping from the end instead of the beginning?

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus wouldn't it be the same thing? I'd still need to keep track of the temps somehow

Comment: But you'd have the information from the previous iteration to use. You'd just have to compare the current and previous temps each iteration.

Comment: NVM I misread the question. I was thinking # of days in the future that will be warmer

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different tricks you can use for this one. @PlatypusMaximus is trying to point you to one that works when you iterate from the end, but you can also do it when you iterate forward, and I think it's a little easier to understand that way:

1. As you iterate through the array, you keep a list of indexes for which the 'closest following warmer day' hasn't been assigned.  This list is initially empty.
2. For each element, remove all the indexes from the list that have lower temperatures, and assign their 'closest following warmer day' to the current index.
3. When you get to the end, any indexes remaining in the list don't have a 'closest following warmer day', and get 0s.

The trick is this:  Whenever you add an element to the list, all the preceding elements are equal or greater.  The index list, therefore, remains sorted by temperature in decreasing order.  In step (2), that means that you only need to look at elements at the end of the list (you can use a stack) instead of searching through it, and the result is that the whole process takes O(N) time.

Comment: *As you iterate through the array, you keep a list of indexes for which the 'closest following warmer day' hasn't been assigned. This list is initially empty.* . -- so I'm making a new array that is storing just the indices ?

Comment: yes, and you would put the output in a different array or overwrite the temperatures

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the result array with zeroes and iterate the given values by checking the stored values as keys in an object and the indices as values.

If a value is found, which is greater than the value in the temporary object, then assign at the index the delta of oth indices and delete this key from the object.

Assign each index to the object with the temperature as key.

```js
var data = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73],
    //     [ 1,  1,  4,  2,  1,  1,  0,  0]
    result = Array.from(data, _ => 0);

data.reduce((t, v, i) => 
    t.filter(([w, j]) => {
        if (w >= v) return true;
        result[j] = i - j;
    }).concat([[v, i]]),
    []
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks...won't this result in O(n^2) time again though, since it's nested loops?

Comment: More like O(n² /2), in the worst case, but still…you can get the same performance by just nesting loops.

Comment: you have two dimensions and you can only check the first value after you know the second value, and so on. you still need a stack of the old unrelated values and collect new one until you reach the end of the array.